# Cannot sign up for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

The first entrance asks for an ID. Which I do not know because I did not go. I registered the same thing 3 times. I can't write to support because I need to sign in. I registered. And a message came in an email that I was registered

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzyEV.png)

Comment: In order to have an ID you first need to register with an E-Mail

Comment: I registered. And a message came in an email that I was registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not on the Signup page and its a login which you are trying now.

Hope below AWS documentation will help you.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/